# Retrieving data semi annually in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I wanted to retrieve my data in the database semi-annually. i have a code snippet that i used to retrieve my data quarterly which is:

```
select Quarter(TransactionDate) as month, count(*) as counted
from service_invoice
where YEAR(TransactionDate) = "2017"
GRoup by Quarter(TransactionDate)
```

and the output of that query is:

> {"quarterly":[{"Quarter":"1","counted":"2"},{"Quarter":"2","counted":"8"},{"Quarter":"3","counted":"6"},{"Quarter":"4","counted":"6"}]}

which is perfectly divided into 4 quarters. now, i want to do the same using semi-annual data. which splits the data into just two types first hale and second half with the output looking like this:

> {"semi":[{"half":"1","counted":"2"},{"half":"2","counted":"8"}]}

is there any way i could do that? thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `MONTH(TransactionDate)>6` in your `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: Thank you. it worked. can you explain me how >6 did that? because i tried /6 earlier.

Comment: @JJCADIZ, for range from January to June the `MONTH(TransactionDate)>6` is false, but for range from July it is true.